# problem with the reloading of the world in webots R2019a

Tags: java, webots

i use the new version of webots R2019a. In the first step it Works fine, but the problem resid when i reload the world; the interface of the world become white.

my operating system is win 10, and my Graphics Card: AMD Radeon HD 8750M.

thanks for helps.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a compatibility issue with your graphic card.
Can you please make sure your GPU drivers are up to date.

If this still doesn't solve the issue, please try reducing the rendering features, from the preferences (https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/preferences#opengl), please set:

- Anti-aliasing: Disabled
- Ambient Occlusion: Disabled
- Texture Quality: Low
- Disable shadows
- Disable camera anti-aliasing

If it still doesn't work, can you please try opening the following world and let us know if you can see the cube without any problem.

```
#VRML_SIM R2019a utf8
WorldInfo {
}
Viewpoint {
  orientation -0.0034935228130107566 -0.95271917787165 -0.303832130318573 2.300369110947556
  position -0.5345391199802001 0.34023173996490996 -0.3828381341796683
}
Background {
  skyColor [
    0.15 0.45 1
  ]
}
DirectionalLight {
  direction 0.5 -1 0.5
}
Shape {
  appearance Appearance {
    material Material {
    }
    texture ImageTexture {
      url [
        "textures/tagged_wall.jpg"
      ]
    }
  }
  geometry Box {
    size 0.1 0.1 0.1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks for help
the problem is resolved by updating my graphic card drivers. Now it's work fine.